# create a new array from array and your property that contains another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, functional-programming, concatenation

I need create a new array from array and your property that contains another array:

```
bigArray = [
    {
     bigArrayID : 1,
     name: 'Xpto',
     children: [
         {childID:1,Name:'XptoChild1'},
         {childID:2,Name:'XptoChild2'},
     ]
    },
    {
     bigArrayID : 2,
     name: 'Foo',
     children: [
         {childID:3,Name:'FooChild1'},
         {childID:4,Name:'FooChild2'},
     ]
    },
    {
     bigArrayID : 3,
     name: 'Bar',
     children: [
         {childID:5,Name:'BarChild1'},
         {childID:6,Name:'BarChild2'},
     ]
    }
]
```

turn bigArray as result like:

```
result = [
            {
             bigArrayID : 1,
             name: 'Xpto',
             children: [
                 {childID:1,Name:'XptoChild1'},
                 {childID:2,Name:'XptoChild2'},
             ]
            },
            {childID:1,Name:'XptoChild1'},
            {childID:2,Name:'XptoChild2'},
            {
             bigArrayID : 2,
             name: 'Foo',
             children: [
                 {childID:3,Name:'FooChild1'},
                 {childID:4,Name:'FooChild2'},
             ]
            },
            {childID:3,Name:'FooChild1'},
            {childID:4,Name:'FooChild2'},
            {
             bigArrayID : 3,
             name: 'Bar',
             children: [
                 {childID:5,Name:'BarChild1'},
                 {childID:6,Name:'BarChild2'},
             ]
            },
            {childID:5,Name:'BarChild1'},
            {childID:6,Name:'BarChild2'}
        ]
```

Each children must be a element in new array.

I need a new array with all father and all child as object.

I need turn child as sibling of your father in new array.

I think I need use concat and/or spread array function...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you are correct, you can use [`Array#reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and then [`Array#concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) each element and its children to the accumulator within the callback:

```js
const bigArray = [{"bigArrayID":1,"name":"Xpto","children":[{"childID":1,"Name":"XptoChild1"},{"childID":2,"Name":"XptoChild2"}]},{"bigArrayID":2,"name":"Foo","children":[{"childID":3,"Name":"FooChild1"},{"childID":4,"Name":"FooChild2"}]},{"bigArrayID":3,"name":"Bar","children":[{"childID":5,"Name":"BarChild1"},{"childID":6,"Name":"BarChild2"}]}]
const result = bigArray.reduce(
  (result, element) => result.concat(element, element.children),
  []
)

// stringify is simply to prevent side-effects
// of stack snippet console behavior
console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2))
```

Comment: Awesome, exactly. =)

Answer (score 0):

Original

```
var resultArray = bigArray.concat(bigArray.map(function(item) {
  return item.children;
})
```

With order

```
var result = [];
for(var i = 0; i < bigArray.length; i++) {
  result.push(bigArray[i]);
  for( var y = 0; y < bigArray[i].children.length; y++) {
    result.push(bigArray[i].children[y]);
  }
}
```

With functional programming and order

```
var result = [];
bigArray.forEach(function(item) {
  result.push(item);
  item.forEach(result.push);
})
```

Comment: This does not produce the same order as in the given result in the question.

Comment: yeah it won't, let me try using some loops instead of functional programming

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but OP didn't asked for ordering

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your question correctly but it seems to me that you want to flatten the hierarchy? If the ordering is not really important then below solution might helps

```
let childArray = [];
bigArray.forEach(x=> {
  childArray = [...childArray, x.children]
});

let answer = [...childArray,...bigArray];
```

The idea is to loop thru all the father in order to grab all their children and store all children into one array, then merge both the children with father into single array

Answer (score 0):

`Array#reduce` into `Array#concat` is known as [`Array#flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap), which is currently stage-3. This is also known as `#chain` according to [Fantasy Land Monad spec](https://github.com/fantasyland/fantasy-land#monad).

You can use it like this

```
const result =
  bigArray .flatMap
    (node => [ node, ...node.children ])

console.log (result)
// [ { bigArrayID: 1, name: 'Xpto', children: [ ... ] }
// , { childID: 1, name: 'XptoChild1' }
// , { childID: 2, name: 'XptoChild2' }
// , { bigArrayID: 2, name: 'Foo', children: [ ... ] }
// , { childID: 3, name: 'FooChild1' }
// , { childID: 4, name: 'FooChild2' }
// , { bigArrayID: 3, name: 'Bar', children: [ ... ] }
// , { childID: 5, name: 'BarChild1' }
// , { childID: 6, name: 'BarChild2' }
// ]
```

If you don't have it in your environment, you can easily polyfill it

```
Array.prototype.flatMap = function (f)
  { return this.reduce
      ( (acc, x) =>
          acc .concat (f (x))
      , []
      )
  }
```

Run a full demonstration of the program in your browser below

```js
Array.prototype.flatMap = function (f)
  { return this.reduce
      ( (acc, x) =>
          acc .concat (f (x))
      , []
      )
  }

const bigArray =
  [ { bigArrayID: 1
    , name: "Xpto"
    , children:
        [ { childID: 1, name: "XptoChild1" }
        , { childID: 2, name: "XptoChild2" }
        ]
    }
  , { bigArrayID: 2
    , name: "Foo"
    , children:
        [ { childID: 3, name: "FooChild1" }
        , { childID: 4, name: "FooChild2" }
        ]
    }
  , { bigArrayID: 3
    , name: "Bar"
    , children:
      [ { childID: 5, name: "BarChild1" }
      , { childID: 6, name: "BarChild2" }
      ]
    }
  ]

const result =
  bigArray .flatMap
    (node => [ node, ...node.children ])

console.log (result)
// [ { bigArrayID: 1, name: 'Xpto', children: [ ... ] }
// , { childID: 1, name: 'XptoChild1' }
// , { childID: 2, name: 'XptoChild2' }
// , { bigArrayID: 2, name: 'Foo', children: [ ... ] }
// , { childID: 3, name: 'FooChild1' }
// , { childID: 4, name: 'FooChild2' }
// , { bigArrayID: 3, name: 'Bar', children: [ ... ] }
// , { childID: 5, name: 'BarChild1' }
// , { childID: 6, name: 'BarChild2' }
// ]
```

If you want the indices and context switching like `Array#map` and `Array#reduce` and `Array#filter` provide, you can add those too

```
Array.prototype.flatMap = function (f, context)
  { return this.reduce
      ( (acc, x, i) =>
          acc .concat (f .call (context, x, i, this))
      , []
      )
  }
```